# sqlcipher on windows using cygwin

Tags: sqlite, cygwin, sqlcipher

I am using this site here. http://retroshare.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Win32CompileLibrariesMingw#Compile_OpenSSL

and I have come across a problem. The error is

```
In file included from /usr/include/w32api/windows.h:95:0, from sqlite3.c:9607:     
/cygdrive/c/sqlcipher-2.2.0/../openssl-1.0.1c/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:153:29:     error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant typedef struct X509_name_st X509_NAME; 
/cygdrive/c/sqlcipher-2.2.0/../openssl-1.0.1c/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:199:33:     error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant typedef struct ocsp_response_st OCSP_RESPONSE;
Makefile:573: recipe for target 'sqlite3.lo' failed
make: *** [sqlite3.lo] Error 1
```

I opened the `ossl_typ.h` file to find only 1 line in it so i am not able to trace the error. Thank you for your help!

Comment: this is my ossl_typ.h file.. https://www.dropbox.com/s/myia2mcdnwk73dz/ossl_typ.h

Comment: ha! you got those instructions to work?  first it assumed by compiler was `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` and after I fixed that I got `tcl8.6.0/generic/tclPort.h:25:28: fatal error: tclUnixPort.h: No such file or directory
`. And that's just trying to compile tcl8.6!

Comment: @Michael lol.. i did get then to work.. but after it all i thought i wasted my time.. so i created an encryption file and used that to encode and decode the details of my SQLite file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across the same problem trying to build sqlcipher. The problem is that recent versions of minGW define X509_NAME and OCSP_RESPONSE.

You need to add `CFLAGS="-DNOCRYPT"` to your `./configure`, e.g. `./configure --enable-tempstore=yes CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2 -DNOCRYPT -lcrypto"` in order to tell the compiler not to define these constants first.

Here is a link that explain the problem : http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-12/msg00194.html

Comment: Thank you. I also found renaming the X509_NAME helps. Thanks a lot..:)

Comment: openssl suffers from the same issue when compiled with mingw64. -DNOCRYPT at config/Configure time fixes.